# Telerik MVC export to excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, export, telerik-grid

I was using Telerik Grid in MVC3 project. In this I have to use the functionality of exporting. In order to export data, I need all the currently available items should be exported as excel format.

I done with exporting. But I need to export all the data currently are available in the grid. It means when filtering Not only the current page's data, It should export all the filtered data's.

I have done something like this: But its not exporting only the filtered data's but all the data's in the grid.

**View Code**

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
            .ToolBar(commands => commands
                .Custom()
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                    .Text("Export to Excel")
                    .Action("ExportExcel", "Grid",
                            new { page = 1, orderBy = "~", filter = "~" }))

        .DataKeys(keys =>
        {
            keys.Add(Id => Id.Itemid);
        })
```

**Action Method in my Controller**

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(int page, string orderBy, string filter)
    {
        IEnumerable orders = GetItems()
                             .AsQueryable()
                             .ToGridModel(page, int.MaxValue, orderBy,
                                          string.Empty, filter).Data;
```

Is there any way that I can do with this. Please help for this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example shows how to export only the relevant data: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/customcommand

There is also a code library project which shows how to export the grid data to Excel: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-mvc/grid/export-to-excel.aspx

Comment: in every example i see that we need to repopulate the list, is there is a way to export the grid ? I an excel with manipulated data making into the grid. I need to export that, since the file is uploaded and deleted i cannot repopulate the grid.